# Flex Not Behaving as expected within Grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a flex display living in a grid to behave like I want. Upon resizing the browser, the flex area refuses to drop below 2 columns no matter what I tinker with and am at a loss as to what to do. I've just taken up markup/coding and am still in the phase of layouts. I'm trying to leverage the powers of Grid and Flex together but am having minimal luck.

Here is what I have so far....please disregard and styling as this is just me tinkering.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(autofit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: autofit 250px 1fr autofit;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h"
    "c c c"
    "p p p"
    "f f f";
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

.main-box {
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.text-wrap {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.main-box p {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.green {
  grid-area: h;
}

.red {
  grid-area: c;
  background-image: url("img/bgmain.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 250px;
}

.blue {
  grid-area: p;
}

.yellow {
  grid-area: f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Grid/Flex Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="green">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="red">Test</div>
      <div class="blue">
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="main-box">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300/?webdesign"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="text-wrap">
              <h3>Project Name</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
                error ea corporis perferendis facere exercitationem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-box">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300/?webdesign"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="text-wrap">
              <h3>Project Name</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
                error ea corporis perferendis facere exercitationem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-box">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300/?webdesign"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="text-wrap">
              <h3>Project Name</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
                error ea corporis perferendis facere exercitationem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-box">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300/?webdesign"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="text-wrap">
              <h3>Project Name</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
                error ea corporis perferendis facere exercitationem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-box">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300/?webdesign"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="text-wrap">
              <h3>Project Name</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
                error ea corporis perferendis facere exercitationem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-box">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300/?webdesign"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="text-wrap">
              <h3>Project Name</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum
                error ea corporis perferendis facere exercitationem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yellow">
        <span>Copyright &copy; Designed by: Useless Dipshit</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `autofit` --> `auto-fit` and this value is only allowed inside repeat

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, I'm a noob.

I forgot:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

That solved everything for me.